# Register click event to children of given div / a with class

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<div class="sidenav-contact__types">
    <div class="sidenav-contact__type js-sidenav-contact__type" data-contact-type="call-me-back">
        <figure>
            <svg class="sidenav-contact__icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/etc/designs/site/img/icons.svg#caller-inverse"></use></svg>
        </figure>
        <h5>Call me back</h5>
        <p>Talk to a Representative about our range.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidenav-contact__type js-sidenav-contact__type" data-contact-type="contact-us">
        <figure>
            <svg class="sidenav-contact__icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/etc/designs/site/img/icons.svg#info-inverse"></use></svg>
        </figure>
        <h5>Contact Us</h5>
        <p>For FAQs, feedback, suggestions or media.</p>
    </div>

    <a class="sidenav-contact__type" href="http://site" data-contact-type="new button">
        <figure>
            <svg class="sidenav-contact__icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/etc/designs/site/img/icons.svg#recall-inverse"></use></svg>
        </figure>
        <h5>Information</h5>
        <p>vehicle is affected.</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is detect when a user clicks inside a `div` or `a` with the given class `sidenav-contact__type`, when clicked I then need to retrieve the `data-contact-type` value.

Now I could of course target this class in general, but when I click on the `h5`,`p`,`figure` or `svg` the script doesn't run due to none of those elements having the class `sidenav-contact__type`

The javascript I currently have is:

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName('sidenav-contact__type');

for(var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++){

    myElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

        console.log('here');

        //get data-contact-type from div or a

    });

}
```

Can a `javascript` guru please show me how I can register a click event on the children elements of the parent element that has the class `sidenav-contact__types`

note: has to be in `javascript`

Comment: Which browser are you using? I've tried out in Chrome and Firefox and when I click in child element of `div` or `a` I get each time the `here` message on the console. (https://jsfiddle.net/myktnaj6/) Isn't it working as expected?

Comment: Strange, working now maybe it was a cache thing.  Either way would you know how I can retrieve the `data-contact-type` ?

Comment: use `this` inside the function `this.dataset.contactType`. See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/skmqya0u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can retrieve the data `contact-type` attribute. Note the camelcase notation of `contactType`.

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName('sidenav-contact__type');
for(var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++){
        myElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

        console.log(this.dataset.contactType);

    });
}
```

See here your working example: https://jsfiddle.net/skmqya0u/

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav-contact__type, .sidenav-contact__type *"); //select every class element and it's childs
for(var i in myElements){
    myElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

        console.log('here');

        //get data-contact-type from div or a

    });
}
```